# Android serialization object to xml

Tags: java, android

Мне нужно сериализовать объект в XML, а затем сохранить его в файл с возможностью десериализации. XMLEncoder и XMLDencoder в Андройде не работают. Там есть [класс Xml](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Xml.html), который, вроде как и применяется для сериализации, но я не понимаю, как он работает. Можете привести примеры сериализации и десериализации?

Comment: Попробуйте покопать в сторону https://habrahabr.ru/post/116830/

Comment: @Chubatiy, зачем мне использовать стороннюю библиотеку, если есть стандартные средства?

Comment: Если не хотите использовать стороннюю библиотеку, то читайте оф документацию - https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html

Comment: @NikotinN, там происходит чтение данных из Xml, в результате получают не объекты, а строки. Смысла в этом нет.

Comment: Стандартные классы не позволяют сериализовать\десериализовать XML. Вам либо придется использовать стороннюю библиотеку, либо придется написать ее самому, то есть начать с `читайте оф документацию - developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html`

Comment: @metalurgus, за монитором 21 век, а нужно писать самому сериалзацию? Меня устраивает java.beans.XMLDecoder и java.beans.XMLEncoder. Их как-то можно выпелить?

Comment: За окном 21 век, кто-то еще использует XML? Самому писать не надо, можно использовать библиотеки, *это не противозаконно*. Вы можете просто найти исходник класса, который вам нужен, и скопировать в свой проект, что по сути и будет *использованием сторонней библиотеки*. Почему он не включен в Android SDK? Я думаю ,что сокрее всаего по каким-то глупым правовым соображениям (патенты, лицензии, и прочий бред). Но вы по этому поводу не можете ничего сделать, как и я.

Comment: А что сейчас используют, если не Xml?